# How to personalize equals for a class and test equal values in a set?

Tags: java, testing, set, equals

I have to overwrite the equals for my train class which has three attributes : number, wagons and type; Two trains are equal only if their numbers are the same. I have to test whether are duplicates in my train SET. How can I do that ? 
This is what i've done so far :

```
public class Train {
    private int number;
    private String type;
    private int wagons;

    public int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(int number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public int getWagons() {
        return wagons;
    }

    public void setWagons(int wagons) {
        this.wagons = wagons;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        Train otherTrain = (Train) obj;
        boolean equal = false;
        if (otherTrain.getNumber() == this.getNumber()) {
            equal = true;
        }
        return equal;
    }
```

Trains DAO :

```
public class TrainsDAO {
    private Set<Train> trainSet = new HashSet<Train>();

    public Set<Train> pupulateTheSet() {
        Random random = new Random();

        for (int i = 1; i < 1000; i++) {
            Train train = new Train();
            train.setNumber(random.nextInt(10));
            train.setWagons(random.nextInt(30));
            train.setType("Inter-city");
            trainSet.add(train);
        }
        return trainSet;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TrainsDAO trainsDAO = new TrainsDAO();
        Set<Train> trains = trainsDAO.pupulateTheSet();
        for (Train train : trains) {
            System.out.println(train);
        }
    }
}
```

And the tests:

```
public class TrainTest extends TestCase {

    private TrainsDAO trainsDAO = new TrainsDAO();
    private Set<Train> trainSet = trainsDAO.pupulateTheSet();
    public TrainTest(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    @Override
    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
    }

    @Test
    public void testIfThereAreEqualValuesInSet() {
        assertTrue(!duplicateFound());
    }

    private boolean duplicateFound() {
        //check if there are duplicates in the set return true if there are no false otherwise
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have implemented hashCode and equals properly Set won't allow duplicates, further more as per documentation hashCode and equals implementation should be similar such that, if a.equals(b) then a.hashCode() == b.hashCode()

Comment: You need to override `hashCode` too, in a way consistent with `equals`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `equals` override as implemented right now may throw:

- `NullPointerException` if the argument is `null`
- `ClassCastException` as there's no `instanceof` check before casting the `Object` argument to `Train`

You may want to fix that.

More importantly for hash-based collections, you need to `@Override` the `Object#hashCode` method consistently with `equals` (that is, by returning a hash code based on your train number).

Overriding `hashCode` correctly will ensure your `Train`s will be put in different hash buckets if their numbers are different.

Also note: it seems pointless to have unit tests checking for duplicate values in a `Set` - the whole point of a `Set` is that it does **not** allow duplicates.

Docs [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29).